# How to detects objects and views inside app?

Tags: android, object, android-view

I have searched about this thread but I didn't found useful solution yet.

Following image describe that:-

[image]

After I touch screen the ball created.

The ball come from top of screen and fall on line surface at the last the ball became stable on the line.

How to detect that line?

What should I search for or what should I use?

I appreciate any help.

Comment: You wouldn't.  Whatever data you're using to draw the line/ball should be used as the source for here they are.

Comment: @GabeSechan Thanks, I didn't get you completely, should I use some other engines? unity ? or what you referring for?

Comment: 1.You want to detect the round black object touching the square black object? 2.Are you using Unity engine?

Comment: @Programmer Thanks, the whole question is about something like (best practice) I need to add some physics or somewhat, in android using `canvas` would be stuck solution.

Comment: Ok. I don't program with Java most often and I suggest you remove the Unity tag as you will get answers with Unity physics system which won't be helpful in anyway.

Comment: @Programmer Exactly that's what I want, I want two compare between to cases, because I don't have a good background in this field (games or moving objects)

Comment: I know what you want to do now. You have the wrong tag in your question(unity3d). You should remove that since you are not using Unity. If you are new to game programming, I suggest you use a game engine like Unity, UDK, or Cocos2d for physics stuff.

Comment: @Programmer thanks, I removed it, do you think going through engines will better solution than native java.

Comment: Yes, engine is better. And don't use Java because then your game can only be published on Android. You need to also publish with iOS which brings more income. Cocos2d and C++ should be used. If you already know Java then use Unity + C# since C# is very similar to Java. There is also UDK + C++.

Answer (score 2):

In the for you animate the ball, you need a step to check colision.

```
  if(ball.getBounds().intersects(line.getBounds())
     ball.stop();
```

I did wrote a tutorial on building a Pong game in Android that cover its steps, unfortunatelly it's in portuguese but you can check it out in http://www.pontov.com.br/site/index.php/android/247-android-desenhando-na-tela

Comment: Thanks, but would canvas and matrix do that for me, what if I want add some physics and reliability ? what is the best way for that ?

Comment: The tutorial do explains how to do this on Canvas, you can do your own physics or use a engine.

Comment: The best of engines are those ones that comes with IDEs such Unity or Unreal

Comment: Yeah, so you what's your suggestion ? I go through engine or find some way with android if possible ?

Comment: Engines delivers faster and you can see the result on the way but you will find yourself coding for the IDE, not bad though. Check the source of the pong https://github.com/MarkyVasconcelos/AndroidTechsGames its a eclipse project

Comment: Actually those are called platform, engines does work with only code

Comment: If you want a better answer you need to post relevant code so we can change it

Answer (score 2):

If it's a canvas you can use positions of objects that are drawn on the canvas.

Get Line startX, startY, endX  and endY.

check Ball positionX is between startX and endX, and second check ball positionY is less then startY.

let say it's the line

```
Line line = new Line(10,10, 80,80);
```

After drawing line

```
int startX=10, startY=10, endX = 80,endY=80;
int positionX=ball.getX(), positionY=ball.getY();

if( positionX <= startX && positionX <= endX && positionY <= startY )
    ball.stop();
```